# Progressbar для картинки

Tags: jquery, html, progress-bar, javascript

В общем есть такое:

```
<img src='big_img.jpg'>
```

Сама картинка грузится ооочень долго, так как размер более 4МБ хочу поставить прогресс бар.
Вопрос: как узнать на сколько процентов скачен файл big_img.jpg?

p.s.: подобное есть у fancybox, но не понятно как реализовано :(

Answer (score -1):

[В этой статье](http://incode.pro/jquery/ajax-na-praktike-progress-bar-indikator-protsessa-zagruzki.html), в самом низу, есть ваш случай. Пересказывать тут - не вижу особо смысла.